# Openstack Mitaka: Network issue

Tags: openstack-neutron

Openstack Mitaka: i deployed Mitaka with the help of Ansible playbooks. My issue is I am able to create network and assign an IP to instance but unable to ping VM from any of my node. I am not able to create network with FLAT or VLAN. I can just create a network with VXLAN. To check VM to VM communication I am unable to launch console.